# Calculate page width in a PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-gallery, android-pageradapter

As Gallery View is deprecated, I'm trying to find a solution to implement an Horizontal List with different views (linearlayouts).

The first option was to use HorizontalScrollView it's fine, but I have to generate all the view by code and all views are stored in memory.

Another option is to use Viewpager, I need to implement my custom pagerAdapter and override the "getPageWidth" method to return a value between 0.0f and 1.0f.

The question is:
In layouts I can set the with as a dip value in the XML, but working with PagerAdapter I need to return a float value and I don't know how to calculate this value to work as a dip in layouts.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this to convert to dip

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591868/android-pixels-to-dips

Comment: The problem is that I have to return a value between 0 and 1. I can't return dip or pixels.

Comment: Page adapter holds your fragments.
I dont understand if you want to change to size of the fragments or the size of view pager that holds them.

Comment: I use "getPageWidth" to return the size of every fragment inside ViewPager. If I return 1, the fragment will match the parent size. I need to know how to calculate the value to return because I can't use dip or other values as in the layouts.