# Problems changing imageView Width by code

Tags: android, imageview

When I try to change the width and height of my imageView the app crashes

Java code

```
final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

The app crashes saying

```
08-22 15:14:33.670 E/AndroidRuntime(9917): 
java.lang.ClassCastException:android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

Comment: Please indent your code with 4 spaces so it's properly displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
imageView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

to

```
imageView1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

The error occurs because your ImageView is inside a RelativeLayout, but you are trying to pass it LinearLayout params.

To keep your other layout modifications, you can try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView1.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = 50;
layoutParams.width = 50;
imageView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: But I've declared in the XML file that it should be centered vertically and horizzontally, but it appear in the top left screen

Comment: Check updated answer - if that doesnt work i have another solution, cant test it right now, sorry.

Comment: Worked! But it's possible to set px width insted of dp? I know is not recommanded, but I need it

Comment: Not directly, but you can easily convert px to dp, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591868/android-pixels-to-dips