# How do I access an Android Studio R.dimen value?

Tags: android

I have two closely-related questions.

In `values\dimens.xml` I have:

```
<dimen name     ="small_flag_height">    72sp   </dimen>
```

In code I have:

```
    /* a */ int resId = R.dimen.small_flag_height;
```

At one point today, the assignment statement above was displayed like this:

```
    int resId = 72sp;
```

When I *hovered* over `72sp`, `R.dimen.small_flag_height` was shown in a popup message;

when I *clicked* `72sp`, the statement was changed to that shown above at `/* a */`.

**(a)** How do I get AS to show that value again? (I have no idea how I got it to show the value in the first place.)

*EDIT* If I close the file and reopen it, `72sp` is again displayed. How else can I do this?

---

The statement below merely shows the assigned `int` value for `R.dimen.small_flag_height`, which happens to be `2131099648`:

```
    Log.w("resId","" + resId);
```

**(b)** What do I have to do to obtain the *value* (`72sp`) assigned to `small_flag_height`? (I don't want to display it, I want to use it in a computation.)

Comment: I'm not sure this helps, but try clicking on the resId and theb press ctrl+> this shoukd show the value of your resource.

Comment: As a sidenote, this shortkut also works with method/class bodies the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.small_flag_height);` will give you the dimension in pixels, not dips. You will need to convert pixels to dips to complete your calculation.

Look here to see how to convert pixels back to dips: [Android - pixels to dips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591868/android-pixels-to-dips)

This answer should work:

```
public int getDip(int pixel)
{
        float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (pixel * scale + 0.5f);
 }
```

Comment: It always amazes me how close I am to my own solution when someone posts what I was just on the verge of figuring out: `density` is indeed what I was looking for but hadn't yet found.

Comment: No worries. Good luck with Android. It's a different beast than most other languages/frameworks you've dealt with.

Comment: You got that right! I thought plain ol' Java was a monster (even worse in Eclipse). I don't know how to classify Android, but "friendly" isn't an adjective I'd include.

Answer (score 0):

This answers (b) above:

```
 getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.small_flag_height);
```

However, result is *not* returned in `sp` units--i.e., not `72sp` or `72`, but rather as `159.75002`, and I'm not sure what those units are...

*EDIT* Per doc for `getDimension`: `"Unit conversions are based on the current DisplayMetrics associated with the resources."`

(a) is answered in a comment above.