# How to compute device independent pixel units?

Tags: android, pixel, density-independent-pixel

I am assuming that the terminology *Density-independent pixels* and *Device-independent pixels*, have same meaning.

Density-independent pixels(dip) are a virtual pixel unit, equivalent to one physical pixel on a `160dpi` (MDPI) screen.

`4dip` is equivalant to `320dpi` (XHDPI) screen, because the number of pixels used to render same data on 320dpi screen is `4`(2 pixels across and 2 pixels down).

How do I compute pixel units in dip for `240dpi` (HDPI) screen?

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591868/android-pixels-to-dips/16660172#16660172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDPI is x1.5 for MDPI.

That is 160x1.5 = 240.

On MDPI device, which is standard for dip unit, 1dip is 1px.
On HDPI device, physically same size 1dip is 1.5px.

When you at first know some px value, you can convert it into dip by **deviding by its scale**, for example, so HDPI's scale is 1.5 that you can devide px value by 1.5.

For the same 2dip, HDPI has 3px across and down while MDPI has 2px across and down.

```
2dip => 2px on MDPI
2dip => 2 x 1.5 = 3px on HDPI
```

The concept of **dip** is that 1 dip means physical size of 1/160 inch approxmately, it's a common physical size through all over the devices that have different pixel densities.

Comment: what is the value in `dip` units? `1.5dip`? If yes, How do I interpret `1.5dip`? I mean `4dip` is 2 pixels across and 2 pixels down.

Comment: i am still not clear. How do I interpret, when I say 3dip on MDPI?  Is it 3 physical pixels on a 160dpi screen? If yes, what does this mean?

Comment: @overexchange  *when I say 3dip on MDPI, Is it 3 physical pixels on a 160dpi screen?* Yes, it is.

Comment: So, What does it mean, when I say, *on non-retina iPhones there are 320 physical pixels and also 320 dips*? Mainly, here am confused, when I say 320 dips. Please help me!!! Because I do not understand the meaning of 3 physical pixels on 160dpi screen. What does it mean to say 3 physical pixels on 160dpi screen? Why are we measuring this way?I could not understand the media queries in terms of dpr [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)?

Comment: So non-retina iPhones' screen densities are approximately 160dpi (MDPI) that you can say 320px has a size of 320dip and 3px has 3dip. The reason is to be physical size as primary and px as secondary (dip stays common and px varies for devices).

Comment: But in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhszwkcay2A), it says `160dpi` is baseline density. So, accordingly, `1dip` is `160dpi`, where as `2dip` is `320dpi`. So, `320dip` mean `320*160dpi`. This is, how I convert dip to dpi. Now, you say 320dip is 320px which is confusing

Comment: No, dpi (or ppi) is density (dot per inch or pixel per inch), not a size, it's a kind of ratio. dip is a unit of size, dpi is ratio. dpi is a fixed value on a device.

Comment: Do you mean 1 dip is 1 px, 2 dip is 2px, 100 dip is 100px, If so, What is the advantage of measuring in dips?

Comment: No, 1dip = 1px is only on MDPI devices. For example on XDPI it is 2px. px size can vary on different dpi devices. While dip doesn't.

Comment: OK. So, *Retina iPhones have a width of 640 physical pixels* But these phones have `320dips` because this is 320dpi (XDPI) screen. So DPR = 640/320 = 2. Is that correct? So, to measure in terms of dips one has to know the dpi of screen?

Comment: Yes. You need dpr (derived from dpi) to calculate dip from px.

Comment: So, Is dip concept mainly used for android devices? for ex: css syntax - `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}` or Do we also use for non-android tablets/phones/desktops?

Comment: I don't know but I think it is for mobile touch-based devices. Because our finger tips' size don't change.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783645/how-do-i-visualise-dip-unit-for-hdpi-screen). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DPI calculators like this [one](http://jennift.com/dpical.html).You can check http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#screen-densities-and-icon-dimensions for the DPI scale ratio. Using this, HDPI = MDPI x 1.5 so in your case, the value will be 240

Comment: I am not looking for calculator, I am looking for the process to calculate?

Comment: You can check here for the dpi scale ratio: http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#screen-densities-and-icon-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get a pixel value from dp in consideration of the current device metrics.

```
public int dpToPx(int dp){
    return Math.round(dp*(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi/ DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```