# How do I visualise dip unit for HDPI screen?

Tags: javascript, android, css, pixel, density-independent-pixel

For a `160dpi` (MDPI) screen, `1dip` is `1px`, as shown below,

### [image]

For a `320dpi` (XHDPI) screen, `1dip` is `2px`, as shown below,

### [image]

For a `240dpi` (HDPI) screen, `1dip` is `1.5px`, But,

How do I visualise `1dip` in pixels for `240dpi` (HDPI) screen?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8168844/3110234)

Comment: You have to force the scale/zoom but the OS and/or the hardware might still overwrite it. You might want to read "A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel": http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll I thoroughly read this document today.

Comment: Also this: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths

Comment: Honestly IMHO the solution is to use real life units (cm, mm) and relative units (%, em) according to the standards and then let the client side decide to respect those standards and to what extent.